# How to find the good path for image with Webpack Encore and Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony 4.4 for a project and yesterday I deployed the project on my server.
This is the first time I'm using the package webpack encore. Impossible to find the path for the images

This is the error message :

GET SERVERPATH/images/usersAvatar/5e685c89938b9522796974.jpeg 404 (Not Found)

This is my webpack.config.js file :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('bui/build')
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')


    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    .splitEntryChunks()

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: './assets/static/', to: 'static'}
    ]))

    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: What URL are you using for your images? Where are these images saved? You provide webpack config, but not the file actually giving you an error.

Comment: don't use webpack for  images related to users such avatars or they are uploaded via forms, put theme in the public folder or other folder.
use webpack for the images related to your design and css  only